# Does hitTestObject method require the objects to test to be on the stage?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm looking at the Adobe documentation [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html#hitTestObject%28%29) and it's not clear.

Since I'm having an issue with my app I'm wondering if it could be because I'm evaluating two sprites, one that is on the stage and the other that is created but no addChild'ed

Comment: I heavily edited my answer, it seems in AIR (I guess this is your case since you mention your app) hitTestObject behaves a little different

Comment: yes, I'm targeting AIR..... So the problem is there, I KNEW IT!!!!!! :) thx for the help, I'm going to try to figure out a workaround for this

Comment: you are welcome, and sorry for the initial misleading! good luck ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, the answer depends on which platform you are targeting. In **FlashPlayer**, **hitTestObject** just checks if the bounding boxes of the objects overlap, so as long as you have the correct x and y positions and the correct width and height for your objects you don't need them to actually be on the stage.

However, in **AIR**, probably some kind of code optimization is taking place, and if one of the objects is not actually on the stage it will return false

Let's just tinker a little with the example from the docs, removing just one addChild:

```
import flash.display.Shape;

var circle1:Shape = new Shape();
circle1.graphics.beginFill(0x0000FF);
circle1.graphics.drawCircle(40, 40, 40);
//addChild(circle1);

var circle2:Shape = new Shape();
circle2.graphics.beginFill(0x00FF00);
circle2.graphics.drawCircle(40, 40, 40);
circle2.x = 50;
addChild(circle2);

var circle3:Shape = new Shape();
circle3.graphics.beginFill(0xFF0000);
circle3.graphics.drawCircle(40, 40, 40);
circle3.x = 100;
circle3.y = 67;
addChild(circle3);

trace(circle1.hitTestObject(circle2)); 
trace(circle1.hitTestObject(circle3));
trace(circle2.hitTestObject(circle3));
```

In FP10 we get the following output:

```
true
false
true
```

However, in AIR we get:

```
false
false
true
```

The key difference is that hitTestObject between the circle1 and circle2 is false in AIR because circle1 has not been added to the stage, but in FlashPlayer is true anyways. Thanks to @user1113426 for pointing there was something amiss here!

Comment: Thx @danii, I'm so tired I didn't think about testing that code without the addChild, sorry :) Yep, the problem it's not there...... Argh

Comment: @danii If remove comments from `addChild(circle2)` results will be `false,false,false`. So hitTest counts `addChild`.

Comment: @user1113426 wow you are right, if I compile targeting AIR I get different results... it seems AIR behaves a little different than FlashPlayer in what refers to hitTestObject, so the problem might after all be there... I'll edit my answer for future reference!